# log() from .utils output location

Tags: python

I'm using/editing a module that uses a `log()` function from utils imported using:

```
from .utils import log
```

and then used as

```
    if settings.use_cache:
    if response_json is None:
        log('Saved nothing to cache because response_json is None')
```

in the [utils docs](https://pythonhosted.org/python-utils/python_utils.html#module-python_utils.logger), `.log()` is there as a method

```
 classmethod log(lvl, msg, *args, **kwargs)

Log ‘msg % args’ with the integer severity ‘level’ on the root logger
```

but isn't it being used as a function here?

my questions are, where is the documentation I'm looking for, and how can I read all of the output to log after I've executed some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the package had a utils.py file that defined `log()` which was why the docs for `python_utils.log()` wasn't matching the usage/behavior I saw in the code.

I think I could have known this because `log()` was imported from `.utils` not `utils` where the period indicates a local file